# Setting data-attributes with loop? (more below)

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops, dom

I 'd like to set a data attribute to divs created by looping though an array.

```
let myLibrary = [ ] //the array

for (const book of myLibrary){
    let cover = document.createElement('div')
    cover.textContent =`title: ${book.title}`
        cover.classList.add('bookStyle')     //adding class for css
        books.appendChild(cover)             //appending to class='books'
    }
```

adding delete buttons to books:

```
const addedBooks = document.querySelectorAll('.bookStyle')
    addedBooks.forEach(book => {
        book.addEventListener('click', removeBook)

    let del = document.createElement('BUTTON');
    del.classList.add('delBtn')
    del.textContent = 'x'
    book.appendChild(del)
})
```

I want to do something like this:
(looping through childs, adding data-attribute)

```
for (let i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++){
        book.setAttribute('data-index', i)
    }
```

in the end, a list of "books" would look like something like this:

```
<div class = 'bookStlye' data-index: 0> Title of book</div>
<div class = 'bookStlye' data-index: 1> Title of book</div>
<div class = 'bookStlye' data-index: 2> Title of book</div>
<div class = 'bookStlye' data-index: 3> Title of book</div>
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What is the current result you are getting? Cause looking at the details in the question, it seems everything should work properly.

Comment: `book` is undefined in that for loop that sets the attribute. What errors do you see in dev tools console?

Comment: According to your code, since the `books` are stored in `myLibrary`, you should replace `book` with `myLibrary[i]` in the loop. Or use the `forEach` loop like you did with `addedBooks`

Comment: Or use the same `for of` as you did previously

Comment: use `book.dataset.index = i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const books = document.querySelectorAll('.bookStyle')
books.forEach((book, i) => book.setAttribute('data-index', i))
```

```html
<div class='bookStyle'> Title of book</div>
<div class='bookStyle'> Title of book</div>
<div class='bookStyle'> Title of book</div>
<div class='bookStyle'> Title of book</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies, this worked for me:

const books = document.querySelectorAll('.bookStyle')
books.forEach((book, i) => book.setAttribute('data-index', i))